# Access denied due to invalid subscription key error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

My app has been working fine since I changed my free account to a Pay-As-You-Go account but yesterday I started receiving the *Access denied due to invalid subscription key error*

I haven't changed anything. What can be the source of this error?

Comment: have you tried generating a new subscription key? and change your old one?

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still an issue? I created keys via a new account and am trying them out (for the Cognitive Vision API).

I essentially used the code from here (using my own api key): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp

I am trying to run it locally from my computer via a command line program (is there any reason that would not work? does it have to be hosted on azure?)

Request url: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/recognizeText?handwriting=false

Comment: @Sirpingalot It turned out to be a problem on my end and I solved it. Regarding your problem, I haven't used the Cognitive Vision API but have you tried testing with a simple cURL? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/curl)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft CRIS servers were experiencing down time starting from ~ 10 pm GMT (according to my observation) on Wednesday 04/19 till 9 am GMT Thursday 14/20. I've experienced problems with log in, deployment access. But some of their servers went back and I was able to log in console. However all my deployments weren't accessible including newly created one. So, as their system went down, you might have problems accessing your deployment. Even if error description is related to invalid subscription key, it might be that issue. It's a new service and I still see 500 Internal errors in console often. If issue is still reproducing, I recommend you to contact their support team crservice@microsoft.com. They are very helpful. However they respond during European working hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues when we hit the API limits. It would not be a bad idea to check if either the number of requests per second or the volume has been reached ( in case of bootstrap keys it is 1000 hits)